# Transfering data from MySQL to Mongo

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I have the need to periodically transfer some data from MySQL into mongoDB. The data in MySQL is growing and will be in TB;s soon. The way I am planning on doing this is using standalone java application that will read data from the table using a select * from and then for each row I am planning to add an entry in the mongo collection.

Any better approach to do this?

Comment: That's the best approach as far as I know. Write your own scripts to read data from Mysql and dump into Mongo. Most importantly, make sure that you pay lot of attention on how you are going to lay out your mongodb schema before doing this migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should at least try to limit the select to newer data, for example by using a timestamp or similar and remember the last export date, so you won't have to run through all the data again.